# Google Music Gapless Playback

Tags: google-play-music

I've purchased an album in which the songs are mixed together but there is a gap between songs when playing the album in Google Music. I've read that the Android app has support for gapless playback but can't find anything about the website.

Does anyone know how to "enable" or fix gapless playback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no option to enable gapless playback in the web player. I contacted Google support about the matter and got this response:

> Their is no option for this on the web player, it should be automatic.

The person responding proceeded to refer to it as:

> gape less playback

so I don't know if he or she actually has any idea what I'm talking about, given the grammar errors.

My experience is that it is indeed automatic, but does not work consistently.